# A curious inequality

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, inequalities

Let $r_k>0$ for $k = 1,\ldots, n$, let $\alpha_k, \beta_k\in \mathbb{R}$   be given such that
$|\alpha_k|\le \beta_k\le \frac{\pi}{2}$. Suppose further that
$\left|\sum\limits_{k=1}^nr_ke^{i(\alpha_k+\epsilon_k\beta_k)}\right|\le 1$
for all choices   $\epsilon_k=\pm1$. How to prove 
$$\sum\limits_{k=1}^nr_k\le n\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2n}\right)?$$

The inequality is known (*Proposition 8* in [S.W.Drury, Von Neumann’s inequality for noncommuting contractions, Linear Algebra and its Applications 428 (2008) 305–315](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0024379507004065)), but the proof given there is rather complicated. So I am looking for a concise proof.

Comment: You say it's known. Can you say where the proof is to be found?

Comment: Here it is. Proposition 8 in Linear Algebra and its Applications 428 (2008) 305–315.